# Input shape and data to LSTM with custom generator

Tags: keras, generator, lstm

I'm working on the [M5 challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/m5-forecasting-accuracy) from Kaggle and are seeking a solution with an LSTM.

Concerning the data:

- There are 30490 items where the sales_amount should be predicted for the next 28 days
- 1941 days of complete data (with around 20 feature columns) are provided that can be used for training
- For the 28 days for the prediction period after the 1941st day, all data is available for the features provided until 1941st day except the sales_amount (that needs to be predicted)

My idea was to start with a look back period of 7 days for the sliding windows to capture at least weekly patterns. But when I created the overlapping sliding windows that have to be fed into the LSTM shifted by one day, the data size was already to large to hold in memory, although I already reduced the dtypes as much as possible.

Therefore I created a custom generator that should yield the x / training data and y / labels:

```
def lstm_data_generator(df, target_col='sales_amount', days_per_sequence=7, batch_size=32):
    total_sequences = (len(df) - NUM_ITEMS * days_per_sequence)
    while True:  
        for i in range(0, total_sequences, batch_size): 
            batch_sequences = []
            batch_targets = []
            for b in range(batch_size): 
                if i + b < total_sequences: 
                    start_idx = (i + b) * NUM_ITEMS
                    end_idx = start_idx + NUM_ITEMS * days_per_sequence
                    batch_sequences.append(df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx, :].drop(target_col, axis=1).to_numpy())
                    batch_targets.append(df.iloc[end_idx:end_idx + NUM_ITEMS][target_col].to_numpy())
            yield np.array(batch_sequences), np.array(batch_targets)
```

My questions are:

1. With which data would I train this LSTM? I can provide all data for the features for the 7 days to train but I can also provide all data for the 8th day (except the sales_amount) because I know them in advance given by the competition data.

- So would I generate the x features for 8 days with 7 days of full data and the 8th day with all data (except the sales_amount which would be filled with np.nans or similar) and for the y labels only provide the data from the sales_amount column? But then how can I tell the model, that the 8th training day is the same point in time as the y label?
- Or would I only train with 7 days of complete data and for the y labels provide only the sales_amount column data or the whole data for the day?
- Or with 7 days of all data except the sales_amount and for the y labels only provide the sales amount?
- Or some other solution not mentioned by me..

2. Depending on the outcome of the first question: how do I adjust my current generator and what is the input shape to train the LSTM when I have, say a 7 day look back period where each day comprises 30490 items and 20 features passed in with a batch size of 32? Say the outcome of the first question is to use 7 days for the training with all data and for the y labels use only the sales amount. What I read is the input_shape parameter should be a 3D array containing samples, time steps and features. So the input_shape should be defined as 32, 7, 20? -> but how can I define that each sample has 30490 items in it and how do I structure the yield of the generator accordingly?
3. Depending on the first two questions: what is the input shape of the predict method? The same as for the x training data?

I tried different input_shape variations but I couldn't get it to run..